# ng serve not working but ng build is working

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

When I run ng serve, everything seems to work except for one small issue, the `main.js` file in the `dist` folder does not change when the automatic build occurs as I change one of the component `ts` files.

When I run `ng build`, the changes I've made to my ts files DO clear out the `dist` folder and replace it with the correct `main.js` file.

I would have thought that `ng serve` uses `ng build` under the hood, but it's not in my case.

Any help on what I can look for would be appreciated.

Comment: `ng serve` creates a temporary build and stores in memory, whereas `ng build` creates a production build. What is it you are looking for with `ng serve`?

Comment: @PsyGik I'm having a major problem with caching, and when I look in the dev tools I'm seeing my old code unless I use ng build

Comment: You can run `ng build  --watch` to create a build when you change files, if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution but no idea why this works and happy to hear better answers:

I had to run:

```
ng build --output-hashing all
```

***once*** per repo folder

Thereafter
`ng serve` correctly picks up my changes and reflects them in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: It is becauSe it adds the hash to the file name. Definitely, you are having issues with the caching on your local server.

Comment: I also now delete the `dist` folder and press `Ctrl-F5` on my browser and `ng-serve` seems to work fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng serve` command is intentionally for fast, local and iterative developments and also for builds, watches and serves the application from a local CLI development server.

The `ng build command` is intentionally for building the apps and deploying the build `artifacts`.

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150724/what-is-difference-between-ng-build-and-ng-serve?answertab=votes#tab-top) SO link, there are very good answers in details to understand it in more depth.

Comment: Thanks for that, but according to that link "Both commands ng build and ng serve will clear the output folder before they build the project." this is NOT happening for me.

Comment: If I have `ng build --watch` in one terminal and `ng serve` in another terminal, it all works as it should, so it seems my client files are coming from the `dist` folder rather than memory. That link did help a bit though, thanks again

Comment: Dist folder is for distribution as the name suggest and local build is served differently. It seems be a caching issue may be. Which angular version are you using btw?

Comment: Angular CLI 11.2.8, Angular 11.2.9, however my colleague, on the same versions, with same code, does not have this problem